# When bidding for papers on softconf.com as a reviewer, does it make any difference between answering no or not bidding for a paper?

Tags: peer-review

When bidding for papers on softconf.com as a reviewer, does it make any difference between answering no or not answering for a paper?

I.e., is there difference between:

[image]

and

[image]

?

---

Answering some comments:

http://softconf.com a.k.a. START:

> START V2 is an integrated web-based solution for managing peer-reviewed conferences and workshops. START helps streamline all steps of the editorial process, including paper/abstract submission, committee formation, paper reviews, on-line technical committee meetings, report compilations, author notification, preliminary conference program creation - and a lot more.

Also, [what is “paper bidding”?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/37850/452).

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- [Quora](https://qr.ae/pNr127)

Comment: Could you explain for context what this site is and does?

Comment: And have you asked them?

Comment: https://softconf.com/: "START V2 is an integrated web-based solution for managing peer-reviewed conferences and workshops. START helps streamline all steps of the editorial process, including paper/abstract submission, committee formation, paper reviews, on-line technical committee meetings, report compilations, author notification, preliminary conference program creation - and a lot more."

Comment: So what does "bid on a paper" mean?

Comment: @user111388 [What is “paper bidding”?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/37850/452)

Comment: I would venture a guess: No means that you do not want to have this paper. As chair, I would really avoid giving you this paper. No bid means, you have not seen it, not paid attention, don't care etc. So, you would not be under priority to get it, but if I do not find a reviewer who said yes or maybe, I would allocate it to you after all. Just my guess as how I would use such a system, that's why it's not an answer.

Comment: What @CaptainEmacs wrote matches my experience with EasyChair, which seems very similar to softconf as you describe it. But a particular program chair might have a different interpretation of the bids, which you could only find out by asking him/her.

Answer (score -2):

I can't answer specifically for this service, but in general it can make a small difference if some papers fail to get bids. For some CS conferences, if you answer no for a paper you are unlikely to be asked again if a second round of bids is needed. If you don't answer at all, then not answering will be likely treated as more like "maybe" than "no".

But, while not especially rare, it only happens at the margins.

But it is even possible that a desperate program chair will come back and beg even "no" voters for reviews in a future "ask". Even less likely though.